# No challenge on basic Authentication

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I'm rather new to everything so I'm hoping this is an easy fix!

I've written an API that uses basic authentication.  It works wonderfully on local host, when I try to make a GET call from my browser it will popup asking for my username/password.  I enter it and it does what is should.

However, after I publish it to our server it stops working.  If I do the same thing it just returns an error rather than a challenge.

Here is what it returns on the server side.

> An error has occurred.
>
> No OWIN authentication manager is associated with
>   the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> at
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.SuppressDefaultAuthenticationChallenges(HttpRequestMessage
>   request) at
>   System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()

Comment: does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089196/no-owin-authentication-manager-is-associated-with-the-request) fix it?

Comment: @Jonesy Sorry I should have linked that in my post.  I did read that but from all I can tell that resource is getting built into my project.  Although there is every chance that I am just missing something.

Comment: so the `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` dll is in your bin folder on the server?  Are you hosting it with IIS?

Comment: It must be something to do with your owin host, but I'm not sure what then :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is a good solution but I managed to solve the problem.

After reading this https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/531740

I added  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`  In the web config.

Which gave me the username/password prompt that I needed.

After fixing that I realized that having Basic Authentication turned on in the IIS settings was causing it to loop the login prompt.  Once I turned it off there I had no more problems.

Hope this helps if anyone else gets in this situation.