# Elmah showing, "No OWIN authentication manager is associated with the request."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

My elmah logs is showing this error. This is not happening with every requests. It happening intermittently. MVC 5.2, Web API 2.2, ASP.NET Identity 2 and Azure website is my environment. 
update: Here is my Startup.cs,

```
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(settings.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpanInMinutes),
            Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider(),
            RefreshTokenProvider = new MyRefreshTokenProvider()
        };
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));
```

Checked this [No OWIN authentication manager is associated with the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21089196/no-owin-authentication-manager-is-associated-with-the-request) but not working

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No OWIN authentication manager is associated with the request.
   at System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.GetAuthenticationManagerOrThrow(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.HostAuthenticationFilter.<AuthenticateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerTracer.<ExecuteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.PassiveAuthenticationMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

I was able to reproduct it in my PC. Just restart the app domain and send a request to api. I will get the above error. After that everything will be fine. Here is StackTrace from my local machine,

```
    Project.Api.dll!Project.Api.Helpers.ElmahExceptionHandler.Handle(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerContext context) Line 22 C#
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler.System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.LastChanceExceptionHandler.HandleAsync(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore>(ref System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore stateMachine)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore>(ref System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore stateMachine)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsyncCore(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler handler, System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleAsync(System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.IExceptionHandler handler, System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionContext context, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync>(ref System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync stateMachine)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync>(ref System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync stateMachine)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore>(ref System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore stateMachine)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore>(ref System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsyncCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase contextBase)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll!System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(System.Web.HttpContext context)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.BeginTask(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> taskFunc, System.AsyncCallback callback, object state) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[AppDomain Transition]
```

Not I am using OAuth server that is available in SPA template.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));
```

Comment: pretty quizzy. It would be better to diagnose if you append `ConfigureAuth` method in **Startup.Auth.cs** file. One thing I assume is that, your authentication logic takes too long time or no response from auth logic in some cases.

Comment: @Youngjae, its there in Startup.Auth.cs. I am getting this error only in the when appdomain restart.

Comment: // I mean, please edit this post to add `ConfigureAuth` method.

Comment: @Youngjae, I have added my Startup.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin(UseOwinMethod). This also fixed the  `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.`. I have found a bug in this package which can also be work-around [Why MessageHandler is executing in MVC request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981805/why-messagehandler-is-executing-in-mvc-request)
Related http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/discussions/540202

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a third-party Basic Authentication middleware (`Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication`) and was getting the same error as the OP. I always had a reference to `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`.

Eventually I overlooked these lines in my `App_Start` code:

```
config.SupressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add( new HostAuthenticationFilter("") );
```

After I removed both lines it was working as-intended.

Comment: Removing these lines removes the authentication from your project!

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get access to the owin context in your API? In WebApi, you should use Request.GetOwinContext() (as opposed to HttpContext.GetOwinContext() you would use in a MVC).

Comment: I am not doing anything. It's not my code. I am using Bearer authentication in Web API. The error is coming in HostAuthenticationFilter. I have `config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType));` taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/20/understanding-security-features-in-spa-template.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments